# use full page external image with text overlay

Tags: pdftex

I have a pdf image that is A4 size. The document I am creating is also A4. I want to use this image as the first page of my document (basically, as the cover) and print some text (in white) over it.

How can I do this? Basically, I need to override all margins for this particular page and also make sure it covers the page exactly and keeps fitting perfectly when the final document it is rendered as a pdf. Any suggestions on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{% Add picture to background of THIS page
      \AtPageCenter{% Picture is centred on page
      \makebox[0pt]{% Horizontally centred
          \raisebox{-.5\height}{% Vertically centred
            \includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth]{pgfmanual}}}}}% Actual image

\title{Document}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  Some text comes here
\end{document}
```

[image]

with `tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \begin{scope}[on background layer]
     \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth]{pgfmanual}};
   \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}

  \Large Some text comes here for example
\end{document}
```

Better than `tikz`, one can use `background` package which is based on `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}    %% or firstpage=true instead of pages=some
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
color=black,
contents={%
 \includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth]{pgfmanual}
}
}

\title{Document}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
  \BgThispage                         %% comment this if you use firstpage=true
  \maketitle

  \Large Some text comes here for example
\end{document}
```

Comment: awesome! Thanks a lot for the thorough answer, that looks beautiful. I have tried the tikz answer first, and it works nicely!